# how do i make the width of the label on free contact form wider?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got a form for a website from [freecontactform.com](https://www.freecontactform.com/free.php) how do I make it so that their is more space by Full Name: and all the rest of the fields as I have edited it and made my own custom fields, but it goes onto the next line when it is too long so it would look like this:

(more text) Full N
ame:

the code is here for the html

```html
<tr>
  <td valign="top">
   <label for="Full_Name" class="required">Full Name<span class="required_star"> * </span></label>
  </td>
  <td valign="top">
   <input type="text" name="Full_Name" id="Full_Name" maxlength="80" style="width:230px">
  </td>
 </tr>
```

please note I have spent over an hour trying to google and work out how to do this

Comment: Post what you have tried so we can help you with your problem. A link to an external site is not useful.

Comment: Without code and more context we cannot help you.

Comment: That's not how SO works. You need isolate the problem and debug from there. If you're stuck provide a clear explanation of what isn't working with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, be sure to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: @JayBlanchard added the code to the question now

Comment: how is this a "php" question?

Comment: What do you mean by "wider"?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner sorry mistake, removed now

Comment: I've never seen this freecontactform.com before, but I simply cannot believe this service is real

Comment: `maxlength="80"` and `width:230px` need to change, probably.  `I simply cannot believe this service is real` ... lol ... I couldn't believe Zapier was real I just do the IMAP myself, guess I'm old school in that way.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I am talking about the `label`

Comment: @DasShield - and where was that mentioned? again.  Thanks...

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix in the question

Comment: The question is ambiguous  `name="Full_Name"`  for example `how do I make it so that their is more space by Full Name: and all the rest of the fields`. To me a `fields` is `input` not `label`.  But lets not debate it, anyway.  Depending on your current CSS, you need to make the table wider for the first row.  You could set `white-space: nowrap;` too, provided the width is not restricted.  Which prevents line breaking on spaces.  You could also replace the space with `&nbsp;` (a non-breaking space), which is essentially the same thing.

Comment: But if the width of the table cell or the label is set, then you may have to adjust those.  The best bet is to use the browser debug window f12, which lets you edit the CSS in real time, then once you find the rules you need just copy them to either the HTML or your stylesheet or what have you.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix thanks so much, `white-space: nowrap;` works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided no widths are set on the label or the table cell, you could use

```
/*obviously you can use any selector here that gets the job done*/
label
{
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Or simply put a non-breaking space (`&nbsp;`) in the text:

```
<label for="Full_Name" class="required">Full&nbsp;Name<span class="required_star">&nbsp;*</span></label>
```

That is essentially what nowrap does, is converts all the spaces to be non-breaking.

Obviously if the width is restricted for the label or the table cell you may need to adjust those.

For reference:

> **nowrap** Sequences of whitespace will collapse into a single whitespace. Text will never wrap to the next line. The text continues on the same line until a `<br>` tag is encountered

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp

Personally I would go the CSS route, it's a bit cleaner and easier to read then putting `&nbsp;` all over the place.

Enjoy.